# Zoom multiple UIimageview inside the dynamic UiscrollView without taking any main container view for paging view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uiscrollview

How to zoom ScrollView along with all its content without taking main container view.

I am working on a app where i have to show two image in a scrollview  dynamically like a pager view for 80 images coming from url.i am able to show two images(like pages of book) in scroll view and i want to zoom both image in the scroll view simultaneously without taking any main container view.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be achieved by doing something like below

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
        imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.scrollview.zoomScale, self.scrollview.zoomScale);
}];
```

**Note:** Code has not been tested, please try, and update.

**Update**

```
for(UIView *subview in self.scrollView.subviews){
    for(UIImageView *imageView in subview.subviews){
       [UIView animateWithDuration:.2 animations:^{
           imageView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(self.scrollview.zoomScale, self.scrollview.zoomScale);
       }];
    }
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: No  this not worked for me. in my view two images in two uiimageview on a scrollview.like in scroll view 40 pages in every page two images.i have to zoom both the image simulteniously.

Comment: i want to zoom the both image view on the scroll.i am creating image view dynamically with dynamic tag and my scroll view is also dynamic according to the number of images from server.i think now u can more clear about my problem.thanx for your immediate response

Comment: @RanjanSahu The code should work, but yes you might need to tweak a bit.

Comment: sorry this is not working for me .Thanx a lot for you response.